# tkinter sunvalley theme error when changing the theme to another window after first one was destroyed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, themes

I try to change the theme using `sv_ttk` lib, but i get this error:

```
Lib\site-packages\sv_ttk\__init__.py", line 39, in set_theme
    root.tk.call("set_theme", theme)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "winfo" command: application has been destroyed
```

My code:
Main window:

```
def choose_skin_theme():
    """
        Display a GUI window to allow the user to choose the skin and theme for the chessboard.

        Updates global variables SKIN, THEME, and COLORS.

        This function uses a Tkinter window to prompt the user for skin and theme preferences and updates global variables accordingly.
    """

    def load_chess_data(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            chess_data = json.load(file)
        return chess_data

    def show_last_moves():
        file_path = ".moves_log.json"
        if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
            showerror("ERROR", "No data to show.")
            return

        chess_data = load_chess_data(file_path)
        if chess_data:
            show_chess_data(chess_data)
        else:
            print("Error loading chess data from the file or no data to show.")

    def apply_selection():
        global SKIN, THEME, COLORS, FRAMES_PER_SQUARE
        SKIN = skin_combo.get()
        THEME = theme_combo.get()

        if THEME == 'Default':
            COLORS = [p.Color(240, 217, 181), p.Color(181, 136, 99)]
        elif THEME == 'Dark':
            COLORS = [p.Color(150, 150, 150), p.Color(50, 50, 50)]
        elif THEME == 'Green':
            COLORS = [p.Color(238, 238, 210), p.Color(118, 150, 86)]

        FRAMES_PER_SQUARE = int(anim_combo.get()[0])

        shutdown_ttk_repeat()

    def shutdown_ttk_repeat():
        root.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')
        root.destroy()

    def open_github():
        webbrowser.open("https://github.com/t0ry003/GoodChess")

    def show_chess_data(chess_data):
        top = t.Toplevel()
        ntkutils.dark_title_bar(top)
        top.title("Data Viewer")
        top.iconbitmap("images/game/icon.ico")

        top_window_width = 280
        top_window_height = 250
        top_screen_width = top.winfo_screenwidth()
        top_screen_height = top.winfo_screenheight()
        top_x_position = (top_screen_width - top_window_width) // 2
        top_y_position = (top_screen_height - top_window_height) // 2
        top.geometry(f"{top_window_width}x{top_window_height}+{top_x_position}+{top_y_position}")

        tree = ttk.Treeview(top, columns=('No', 'Player', 'Move'), show='headings', style='Treeview')
        tree.heading('No', text='No', anchor='center')
        tree.heading('Player', text='Player', anchor='center')
        tree.heading('Move', text='Move', anchor='center')
        # make a scroll bar that moves the treeview up and down
        scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(top, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)

        for move in chess_data:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values=(move['number'], move['player'], move['move']))

        tree.column('No', width=30)
        tree.column('Player', width=100)
        tree.column('Move', width=100)

        tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
        scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        tree.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        top.mainloop()

    global SKIN, THEME, COLORS, FRAMES_PER_SQUARE
    root = t.Tk()
    ntkutils.dark_title_bar(root)

    root.title("Good Chess | Settings")
    root.iconbitmap("images/game/icon.ico")

    window_width = 350
    window_height = 625
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x_position = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
    y_position = (screen_height - window_height) // 2
    root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

    main_logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./images/GAME/icon.ico").resize((150, 150)))

    play_icon = t.PhotoImage(file='./images/GAME/play-icon.png')

    skin_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Choose Skin:")
    skin_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=["Default", "Fantasy", "Minimalist"])
    skin_combo.set(SKIN)

    theme_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Choose Theme:")
    theme_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=["Default", "Dark", "Green"])
    theme_combo.set(THEME)

    anim_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Choose Animation Speed:")
    anim_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, width=1, values=["1 (FAST)", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9 (SLOW)"])
    anim_combo.set(FRAMES_PER_SQUARE)

    logo_label = ttk.Label(root, image=main_logo)

    apply_button = ttk.Button(root, text="START", command=apply_selection, image=play_icon, compound=t.LEFT)
    show_moves_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Show Last Moves", command=show_last_moves)

    github_button = ttk.Button(root, text="\u2B50 GitHub", command=open_github)

    logo_label.pack(pady=10)
    skin_label.pack(pady=10)
    skin_combo.pack(pady=10)
    theme_label.pack(pady=10)
    theme_combo.pack(pady=10)
    anim_label.pack(pady=10)
    anim_combo.pack(pady=10)
    apply_button.pack(pady=20)
    show_moves_button.pack(pady=10)
    github_button.pack(side=t.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

    sv_ttk.use_dark_theme() #<-this function
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", shutdown_ttk_repeat)
    root.mainloop()
```

Popup window:

```
def askPawnPromotion():
    """
    Ask the player which piece to promote the pawn to.

    This function uses a Tkinter window to prompt the player for a piece to promote the pawn to.
    """

    def apply_selection():
        global PROMOTION_PIECE
        PROMOTION_PIECE = promotion_combo.get()
        popup.destroy()
        popup.quit()

    global PROMOTION_PIECE
    popup = t.Tk()
    ntkutils.dark_title_bar(popup)

    popup.title("Good Chess | Pawn Promotion")
    popup.iconbitmap("images/GAME/icon.ico")

    window_width = 350
    window_height = 200
    screen_width = popup.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = popup.winfo_screenheight()
    x_position = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
    y_position = (screen_height - window_height) // 2
    popup.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

    promotion_label = ttk.Label(popup, text="Choose a piece to promote the pawn to:")
    promotion_combo = ttk.Combobox(popup, values=["Queen", "Rook", "Bishop", "Knight"])
    promotion_combo.set("Queen")

    apply_button = ttk.Button(popup, text="APPLY", command=apply_selection)

    promotion_label.pack(pady=10)
    promotion_combo.pack(pady=10)
    apply_button.pack(pady=20)
    
    sv_ttk.use_dark_theme() #<-and this function
    popup.mainloop()
    return PROMOTION_PIECE[0]
```

I have 2 windows. One main menu and a popup window that appears when a pawnpromotion (chess game) is happening. If i set the sv_ttk theme for the first window everything is fine. Removing it from the first window adding to the second window also fine. But when i try to set the same theme to both of them it's suddenly not working.

I tried setting the theme in different states of the window, expecting it to work before I destroyed that one window.

Comment: As a general rule you shouldn't be creating more than once instance of `Tk`. That causes lots of problems, and is probably the root of this problem. Tkinter has a `Toplevel` class if you need to create more than one window.

Comment: but what if i need just a popup and hide the first instance of the window? How can i do that?

Comment: Look at the methods `wm_withdraw` and `wm_deiconify` to hide and show a window.

Comment: any way of killing the first instance, or start a fresh one that works?

Comment: That's not normally how a tkinter app should behave. Is there a reason you need two root windows? Why are you not able to use a `Toplevel` for the popup window?

Comment: well I updated an old script and didnt want to modify every part of this software for this ui change. I found something. If a theme is packed as a lib, it's not what you want :))

Best way to do a theming is like tkinter wiki says:
`root.tk.call('source', './images/THEME/sun-valley.tcl')' 'root.tk.call('set_theme', 'dark')`

by using this I created 20 instances that performs and look great. The instance mith is somewhat wrong, as long as u add your sources again and not expect using them without adding them in the new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something. If a theme is packed as a lib, it's not what you want :))

Best way to do a theming is like tkinter wiki says:

```
root.tk.call('source', './images/THEME/sun-valley.tcl')
root.tk.call('set_theme', 'dark')
```

by using this I created 20 instances that performs and look great. The instance mith is somewhat wrong, as long as u add your sources again and not expect using them without adding them in the new instance.

Need the sv_ttk theme as .tcl scripts? Here it is: [sv_ttk as .tcl](https://github.com/formazione/SunValleyttktheme)